# Failure with more than one co-dependant/circular python import

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import python code from one submodule to another, and I am getting an error, but only when I have more than co-dependant import from the package.

From my understanding, this "circular" importing is okay to do in Python. From the way I'd like the code to be organized, I do need these "co-dependant" imports and unless I really have to change it, I'd like to keep my code structured in the same submodules it currently is.

My directory/file structure:

```
./subm1/
  ./subm1_file.py

./subm2/
  ./subm2_file.py

./subm_main/
 ./subm_main_file.py
```

```
# subm1_file.py
# -------------
import subm_main.subm_main_file
print(subm_main.subm_main_file.test)
```

```
# subm2_file.py
# -------------
import subm_main.subm_main_file
print(subm_main.subm_main_file.test)
```

```
# subm_main_file.py
# -------------
import os
import sys
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_path+".."))
import subm1.subm1_file
import subm2.subm2_file
test = "test_variable"
```

I am running `$ python subm_main_file.py` while inside the `subm_main` directory

this works if I only use one module, so if in `subm_main_file.py` I comment out `import subm1.subm1_file`, it will run and print the test variable, and same if i comment out `import subm2.subm2_file` the error always comes one the second import. So in the code I show, the error is in `subm2_file.py`.

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'subm_main' has no attribute 'subm_main_file'
```

It seems very strange to me that this works one time but not the second time with both import statements uncommented out. What can I do to fix this error (and hopefully keep my code organized in its current state)?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet on a post but maybe your issue is that you need to place an **init**.py file inside the root and sub-directories if you want to keep your folder/code structure unchanged...